# How to create a Bound Service in an Android app?

Tags: c#, android, android-service, portable-class-library

I am basically working on a Xamarin.Forms (cross platform) Project which uses Portable Class Library. And I know I cannot run background services from PCL, so I need to get into each platform individually for that. Now I'm stuck in android.

What I need to create is a bound service. So when my app starts, I have 2 buttons, Start and Stop (disabled). I click on start (start button becomes disabled and stop button enabled) it sends a message to my android platform using MessagingCenter to start the service using an Intent and Bind To it.

So I have this in my MainActivity.cs

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StartAppBoundServiceMessage>(this, 
"StartServiceMessage", message =>
{
    Intent objXPathServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(XPathService));
    StartService(objXPathServiceIntent);

    connection = new XPathServiceConnection(this);
    BindService(objXPathServiceIntent, connection, Bind.AutoCreate);

});
```

StartAppBoundServiceMessage is a simple class in my PCL.

Now when I leave my app(using home button or back button or maybe a call comes), I want it to unbind from my service- but my service should still go on. That is why I have started my service using StartService(). But again when it is unbinding it should preserve somethings (like settings that are being used in the service) that had been set from my UI.

The next time when I come back my application should check if my service is running, if it is (it must bind to it again and let me make setting changes or stop the service by clicking on the stop button etc).

I have 2 questions:

1. I am confused on where I should UnBind when my app is leaving foreground, and where to Bind when coming back again. I know how to check if my service is running already, but i dont know where to check it. because back button calls onCreate and home button calls onResume.
2. How to preserve these settings in my service and put them back into my UI when I comeback.

PS: All my service methods will be called from my PCL project.

Note: The requirements are somewhat like a music player but the app is no where close to it.

Comment: Note that requests for tutorials are firmly off-topic here, so I have slightly adjusted your question. Please also do not beg - everyone is a volunteer here.

Comment: thanx halfer, actually im a newbie, will keep that in mind